# Creating a single data slicer based on multiple columns in PowerBI

Tags: database, powerbi, data-visualization

I have a table of ticket data where each ticket is associated with anywhere from one to five tags under the Tag column and one to four regions under the Region column.

I'm looking to create something I can use for visualization later on that will allow me to filter based on the five potential tag values and four potential regions that a given ticket could have--that if a ticket has both EMEA and AMER as regions, one has EMEA as a region, and another has APAC as a region, then I could filter on EMEA and return the first two tickets and not the third. Essentially, I want to make a slicer that has a list of each of the potential single values of the Tag and Region columns and return any data that has that category for each. The plan would be, obviously, that these would be two separate slicers.

For reference, originally Tag and Region were all a single column, but I split them out using delimiters so that there's four region columns each with a single potential entry (Region 1, Region 2, Region 3, Region 4). I did the same for Tag, so there's now five tag columns (Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3, Tag 4, Tag 5).

I've tried doing the following so far:

> Slicer Table (Type) =
> UNION(SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(TABLE,TABLE[Region 1] <> BLANK()),"Name", TABLE[Number],"Region 1",TABLE[Region 1]),SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(TABLE,TABLE[Region 2] <> BLANK()),"Name", TABLE[Number],"Region 2",TABLE[Region 2]),FILTER(TABLE,TABLE[Region 3] <> BLANK()),"Name", TABLE[Number],"Region 3",TABLE[Region 3]),FILTER(TABLE,TABLE[Region 4] <> BLANK()),"Name", TABLE[Number],"Region 4",TABLE[Region 4]))

However, instead of returning a single value for each region on which you can filter, it returns multiple values for each region--showing AMER as a filter option twice, etc. The same goes for trying to use this with the Tag column.

Any advice, or maybe easier ways to go about this?

Comment: Please try unpivoting the table, which is 4 region columns into 1 column and 5 tags column to other single column. You can do these operations in Power Query.

Comment: Hi Hain!

Thank you! I've merged them back into a single column and unpivoted. How should I go about using the newly created attribute/value columns to slice?